# Different set of characters to interpret as keyword for different files - vim

Tags: vim, file-type

When I type `w` as for next word in vim, vim decides what is a word by searching the character set set by command `:set iskeyword+=`. I want to specify this settings per file type, so when I have `>>=` in haskell, it is interpreted as a word, but when I have `<td>Field</td>` in html it is not a whole word.

How can I do this in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to enable an option for certain filetypes, use `:setlocal option=value` instead, and put the corresponding `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, where `{filetype}` is the actual filetype (e.g. `java`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype} setlocal option=value` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.